# Pagination in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

For my project in Elasticsearch, I was using from and size to give pagination. But the problem I am facing is when it comes to a big result set because as Elasticsearch mentions from+size should never be greater than 10000.

Now the benefit of using From and size was that when representing the result in UI I could jump to any page I want by giving the from and the size value in query. I am not sure how to achieve that using scroll. Lets say I do a search with scroll with given size 50. And the result has 29000 doc, so given the size of result we will have 580 pages, If I click on 101 page how it will behave if we use scroll. Any suggestions how we can handle this ??

Thanks and regards
Ashit

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: show your query plz

Comment: The problem here is that scroll does not let you to go to a specific page. because you can fetch **only the next page** using scroll id of current page.